# Remove border around footer widget

Tags: widget, border, footer, transparent

I'm having trouble removing the border around a widget in my footer are. I applied the code below to my custom CSS in wordpress but nothing is changing.  My website can be found [here.](http://www.dontcursekids.com/)

```
#widget-5 {border:transparent;}
```

Comment: you are using wrong id. Your widget id is `id="cnss_widget-5"`. Change your css to `#cnss_widget-5 {border:transparent;}`

Comment: Hello,
I tried those ids beforehand and didn't get any changes in the border except the color. I used #widget and it did the trick. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the css:

```
.sfwa_footer_area{border: none;}
```

Comment: thanks. It didn't work at first but I changed sfwa_footer_area to widget and it worked fine. thank you once again.